# WPF combobox selected index

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles

I have a combobox which I'm setting it's itemsSource after getting it from a database, for some reason the combobox doesn't show the first item.

My comboBox:

```
 <ComboBox Text="Add To Message:" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedMessage}" Style="{StaticResource comboStyle}"/>
```

My style:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="comboStyle">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItemId}" Value="-1">
                    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="1"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Probably SelectedValue and SelectedIndex are conflicting. Both impact the same value.

Comment: When you update the Messages property do you set SelectedMessage property with the first message?

Comment: No, I'm working MVVM so it's not possible

Comment: Well your SelectedMessage property is in VM...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `SelectedIndex` you should set `SelectedMessage`:

```
// get data from db...

SelectedMessage = Messages.FirstOrDefault();
```